# Configure eclipse to work with tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, configuration

Is there a way to configure eclipse to create dynamic web projects with the standard folder structure?
Like :

```
/root
   /WEB-INF
      /web.xml
      /lib
      /classes
      /...
   /META-INF
      /...
```

Instead of

```
/root
  /src
  /build
  /WebContent
     /WEB-INF
      /web.xml
      /lib
      /...
   /META-INF
      /...
```

I know I can export the project into a *.war file, but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution that looks like Shinichi Kai's one. I changed the default output folder like he did,and instead of setting the `docBase` in the `server.xml`, I created a new context.

To do so,I created an xml file in `%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/Catalina/localhost/`. In this file, the context is defined like this: `<Context docBase="<Eclipse_Workspace_Path>\<Project_Name>\WebContent"/>`

It's cleaner than setting the docBase directly in the `server.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to set `docBase` to your project's root folder? If this is the case, you can change Default output folder from `YourProject/build/classes` to `YourProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` in Java Build Path.

And, set `docBase` to `YourProjectRoot\WebContent` in your server.xml.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's more or less what I want. Thanks for the classes folder config, but I don't really want to modify the server's configuration. I want to configure eclipse to put the WEB-INF and META-INF at the root of my project, like in the stadard structure, if possible.

Comment: You can customize WEB-INF and META-INF location in Deployment Assembly in the project's properties. However, Deployment Assembly does not provide the way to map the project's root to the Deploy Path...